# \n not working in PHP email

Tags: php, email

I have a career page with a resume upload form. I've exhausted my resources trying to figure out why the line breaks aren't occurring when the form processes and sends the info to my inbox. I am using \n and it should be working but it seems to ignore it and run all the submitted info onto one line. I'm not a big php form person, especially with uploading files, so I utilized an existing one and grew upon it. I'm sure its something very simple, but any thoughts would be much appreciated.

```
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\n";
$headers.="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

//Message

$message = "--".$boundary."\n";
$message.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";
$message.="\n";
$message.=" \n First Name: $fname; \n Last Name: $lname; \n Email: $email; \n Position: $position_type; \n Comments: \n";
$message.="\n";
$message.=clean_msg(nl2br(strip_tags($yourmessage)));
$message.="\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML mail, whitespace is ignored. Use `<br/>` instead.

Comment: Duh! I didn't even think about that. Thank you so much, that totally did the trick! Works like a charm.

Comment: @Petey, if this is your answer, don't forget to give it the big green checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

MIME Headers, In this case E-Mail's implamentation of them, are always windows style `\r\n` aka `CRLF` (Carriage Return, Line Feed).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I tried using \r\n and it still didn't pick it up. I'm trying to figure out if there's something else that would possibly be preventing it from picking it up?

Answer (score 0):

Try all three `\r\n<br />`. Then just work your way to what you need.

Comment: \r\n will not work when mail is in html format.Just <br/> is enough.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here:

["\n" is not getting in OUTLOOK email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996621/n-is-not-getting-in-outlook-email)

\r\n wasn't working for me so I tried adding spaces before the \n and that seemed to do the trick.  I needed to make the line at least 60 characters long for the problem not to happen anymore.