# "\n" is not getting in OUTLOOK email

Tags: php, outlook

```
$str = "Hello Jagdish \n\n";
$str .= "this is nice evening \n\n";
$str = stripcslashes($str);
mail($to, $subject, $message);
```

when checking this email in the outlook no "\n\n" is coming in that
what is the reason ?
how to get those in the email ?

Comment: Are there newlines?  Or is everything bunched up one one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Outlook re-formats plain-text e-mails as it sees fit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287816).  This can be turned off in the options, but if you are sending stuff to your customers in plain-text, there is nothing that can be done about this.

The theory is that it is trying to detect a fixed-width column, and remove the fixed-width so the e-mail is more readable.  In my experience, this simply produces annoyance, as you are experiencing.

If you were to send an HTML version of your e-mail, it would be used and formatted correctly.  (Note that you should always send a plain-text version in addition to the HTML version, for clients that can't use the HTML version.  Outlook uses the HTML version by default, if it exists.)

Comment: I don't know if this still applies to newer versions of outlook.  It used to be that if you prefixed the lines with whitespace, then it would not automatically remove line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook removes linebreaks automatically in plain text e-mails.

If it does, it tells you so (well, at least Outlook 2003 did) and you got the option to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue (in Java) generating plain text emails using \n and.  It was annoying because using 2 \n's for me added both new lines, so I could do zero or two new lines but not one.

I tried \r\n but it didn't seem to do the trick.

I figured out a hack that fixed my problem.  I just added a bunch of spaces after the end of the line and before the \n.  I figured out that I needed exactly 3 spaces for it to work.

body += "words words words   \n";

Because my line was 57 chars long without the spaces, I'm assuming that outlook is combining lines that have less than 60 spaces (57 + 3 = 60).  Outlook is terrible for making me do this but it worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

Windows uses `\r\n` line breaks, try replacing every `\n` with `\r\n`. 
Also, you need to remove `$str = stripcslashes($str);` as it converts `\n` into `n`

Comment: That is not the problem here.

Comment: This answer is incorrect; the double-quote mechanism will unescape "\n" into character `0x0A` as soon as the statement is done parsing; `stripcslashes` will have **no effect** in this case.  You can test this simply with `echo strlen("\n");` -- the output is 1.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. It is a feature of Outlook and has nothing to do with the kind of line breaks. See my answer.

Comment: strpcslashes is nothing do with "\n"